# Pi4 Electron GUI using Buildroot

Tags: pi-4, buildroot, electron

**Goal:**

I'd like to build an RPi4B image using Buildroot that can run web technology (e.g. NodeJS and Electron) as a touchscreen kiosk.

**What I've Tried:**

After initially using the latest stable version of Buildroot `2021.11.2`, I found the latest tag `2022.02-rc3` has the best result.  Older Buildroot versions would not build some of the packages successfully.

I initialized Buildroot with the `raspberrypi4_64_defconfig` and added various graphics packages and libraries.  The following are the key packages I added:

- openbox
- mesa3d
- x11 (xorg server, xcb util, etc)
- gtk3
- xf86 fbturbo driver
- nodeJS v14.18.3 with npm 8.5.3 --> installs electron 17.1.0

I initialized a basic Electron app on the RPi filesystem, with `npm init` and `npm install` commands, following this guide:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/printing-in-electronjs/

The RPi boots, shows `/dev/dri/` devices and is able to start an X session as non-root user.  I can also use commands like `fbtest` and `feh` for a wallpaper.  However, when running Electron and having `DISPLAY=:0` in the environment, I encounter errors:

```
Mar 08 15:51:01 buildroot npm[296]: > electron-printing@1.0.0 start
Mar 08 15:51:01 buildroot npm[296]: > dbus-launch electron --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer --enable-logging .
Mar 08 15:51:06 buildroot npm[353]: [353:0308/155106.755187:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(454)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
Mar 08 15:51:06 buildroot npm[309]: /home/developer/electron-printing/node_modules/electron/dist/electron exited with signal SIGTRAP
Mar 08 15:51:06 buildroot systemd[1]: ui.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 08 15:51:06 buildroot systemd[1]: ui.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Initially the `npm start` command was just `electron .` but I added the other options per resources online.

**Questions:**

1. Has anyone successfully run Electron via a Buildroot image on the
   RPi4B?  Is this possible?
2. Are there particular versions of Buildroot that have working combinations of the packages listed above?  I suspect I am encountering discrepancies between the packages Buildroot installed (e.g. `libEGL.so`), and those that `npm` is trying to use...but I am not certain.
3. Should I be using other packages than the ones I listed?  I wasn't sure if `mesa3d` or `fbturbo` are the best options in Buildroot for what I am trying to achieve here.  It does seem like `fbturbo` works better than `fbdev`; Electron showed more errors using `fbdev`.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a solution to the `Electron` issue(s) yet.  I am thinking that alternatives like `WPEWebKit` and `Cog` might be a better fit